# android Check mark on button click

Tags: android, button, checkmark

On click of a button , a check mark icon should be displayed on the leftmost corner of the button, when reclicked on the same button , the check mark icon should disppear. Could some on help me out in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an ImageView (lets say tick.png) with visibility Gone,  at the left of the Button. And set its visibilty. Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_tick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/tick"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_tick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Press"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now, on Button click event you set its visibilty:

```
Button btn_tick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_tick);
    btn_tick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ImageView iv_tick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_tick);
                int visibility = iv_tick.getVisibility();
                if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    iv_tick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    iv_tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: But I want the tick mark to be overlapped on the button , not beside the button

Comment: You can also use an ImageButton. With appropriate Images for Checked and normal states. And change them on Click event.

Answer (score 8):

While this is already answered, here's an alternative solution: add a unicode checkmark symbol.  There are two of them: \u2713 and \u2714.  Just add them to your strings:

```
<string name="button_label_on">\u2713 on</string>
<string name="button_label_off">off</string>
```

Of course, you can put this directly into your layout code, too:

```
<Button
   ...
   android:text="\u2713 on"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) widget.

Comment: I dont want a checkbox . The UI should have only a button and when clicked, a tick mark icon should appear on the left corner of the button

Comment: You can tailor the CheckBox widget to look like a tick. Anyway, if you don't(though I think you should) want to use the CheckBox widget, you can add a tick image to the left of the button with its initial visibility set to *gone*, and set it to *visibile* when the button is clicked.

Comment: I couldnt get the latter part of your solution. Could you please let me know as how could you add an image to button and then alter its visibility?

Comment: It's two widgets, a tick image(ImageView) and a button(Button). Layout them consecutively from left to right.